# Why some of my localized XIB files are modified on every build?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder, xib

I'm having hard time with Xcode 4.2 (Build 4C199) changing some of my XIBs on every build:

1. only some XIBs get changed, i.e. some (not all) XIBs localized for
   English;
2. the only change inside is new ref and id values for
   IBUIFontDescription, it goes like that:

`- <reference key="IBUIFontDescription" ref="341344726"/>`
`+ <reference key="IBUIFontDescription" ref="569996084"/>`

or

```
- <object class="IBUIFontDescription" key="IBUIFontDescription" id="272245591">
+ <object class="IBUIFontDescription" key="IBUIFontDescription" id="509661802">
```

Well, I use `ibtool` to make the localization based on strings files, but `ibtool` does not output any warning/info while creating a localized version of XIB based on original XIB and language specific strings file… Here's what does my localization script:

```
ibtool --generate-strings-file Resources/Common/German.lproj/NIB_Localization/View.strings Resources/XIBs/German.lproj/View.xib
ibtool --strings-file Resources/Common/English.lproj/NIB_Localization/View.strings --write Resources/XIBs/English.lproj/View.xib Resources/XIBs/German.lproj/View.xib
```

What I've already tried:

- cleaning Applications directory for every Simulator version installed;
- deleting all derived data for all applications;
- cleaning the project and rebuilding it...

Any ideas?

Comment: Damn, the issue persists after updating to OS X Lion and Xcode 4.2.1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did 2 things:

1. In Finder I deleted the XIBs that got changed all the time (note again: not in Xcode!).
2. The base versions of that XIBs (base localization that `ibtools` uses) I correctly set XIB  deployment and development targets.

... and it worked :) However it still remains a mystery for me, that upgrading to Xcode 4 could cause that issue.